# What does the expression "account for" actually mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

The complete sentence comes from a publication I was reading: "*The current method for fabricating prosthetic sockets is to modify a positive mold to account for the non-homogeneity of the residual limb to tolerate load (i.e., rectified socket)*"

account for = to address?

Comment: *to adjust for* seems a more fitting synonym.

Comment: I was surprised to find that the phrase 'to account for' did not in fact mean 'to take into account'. It was certainly used in the quotation in that sense and is a common enough usage that I recognised it without bothering to check references. I'd have thought this was a good example of English Usage which has moved ahead of the standard definitions and worth having here.

Answer (score 2):

It is being used in the sense of 'to take into account'. So the modification takes non-homogeneity into account. Also, 'to make allowance for'.

Comment: Can you add support to your answer? Perhaps a definition with a source so the answer carries more weight?

Comment: No, cannot supply definition: the quote is using 'account for' in a non-defined way. It seems I was providing an interpretation. I've modified my answer to make this clearer. Will check before I answer in future.